# Messenger style UITextView input

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm working on a simple chat as a part of my App.
I have a list of Chats (i.e. friends) in a Table View Controller and Chat View Controller displaying messages for each chat. Both of them are embedded in a NavigationController, which is embedded in a TabBarController.

I want to place UITextView message text input field in a ChatViewController below my UITableVeiw that shows messages of that chat. I would also like the UITextView to look like it's embedded in a tab bar.
I've run through dozens of manuals tutorials and guides and that's where I got so far.

App simulator screenshots here: nice at the top, buggy at the bottom

[image: App simulator screenshots here: nice at the top, buggy at the bottom]

Main.storyboard screenshot here

[image: Main.storyboard screenshot here]

1. I use UITextView instead of UITextField because I want it to be able to change its size depending on content size
2. I use UIViewController instead of UITableViewController to be able to add another UIView along with UITableView
3. I don't use actual UITabBar to embed my UITextView because it behaves really weird when UITextView needs to change its height. And as far as I understood Apple doesn't support embedding UI element to UITabBar
4. What I do is I hide TabBar in ChatViewController viewWillAppear:

   ```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
   }
   ```

   And I show it again in parent ChatsTableViewController:

   ```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
   }
   ```
5. Once TabBar is hidden, my custom stackView embedding textView and sendButton takes its place and operates quite normally as I want it to.
6. To handle keyboard behaviour properly I have an outlet for my inputStackView bottom constraint (selected on screenshot), which I update on keyboardWillShow/Hide Notifications. Code for that looks like this:

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var inputBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
   var inputBottomConstraintInitialValue: CGFloat!

   //MARK: - Keyboard handling
   private func enableKeyboardHideOnTap(){

       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ChatTableViewController.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ChatTableViewController.keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

       let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ChatTableViewController.hideKeyboard))

       self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
   }

   @objc func hideKeyboard() {
       textView.resignFirstResponder()
   }

   @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

       let info = notification.userInfo!
       let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
       let duration = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double

       UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) { [weak self] () -> Void in
           self?.inputBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height + 8
           self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
       }
   }

   @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

       let duration = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double

       UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) { [weak self] () -> Void in
           guard let `self` = self else { return }
           self.inputBottomConstraint.constant = self.inputBottomConstraintInitialValue
           self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
       }
   }
   ```

Everything seems to work fine at this point:

- TabBar is hidden in a ChatViewController and is shown in ChatsTableViewController
- textView and sendButton embedded in a stackView slide along will keyboard up and down, as shown in simulator screenshots above.

The BUG appears when I *swipe* between ChatViewController and ChatsTableViewController instead of using NavigationControllers

When I start swiping back to ChatsTableViewController, it perform its viewWillAppear method, so tabBarController's tabBar become visible. And if I don't finish that swipe to ChatsTableViewController and go back ChatViewController, ChatViewController's viewWillAppear sets it back to invisible, but the input stackView doesn't get back to it's initial position. It just hangs there above the invisible tabBar.

I've tried moving

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
```

from viewWillAppear to viewDidAppear in ChatsTableViewController.
It fixes the "floating input" issue but it adds a lag of about a second, when ChatsTableViewController is showing without tabBar. Looks not too good either.

Any ideas how that could be fixed properly?
I've been struggling with that issue for about a week))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `ChatsTableViewController` is embedded in in `UINavigationController` and your `ChatViewController` is pushed you can override this `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` in `ChatViewController` which will determine to show your view controller or not:

```
public override var hidesBottomBarWhenPushed: Bool {
    get { return true }
    set { super.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = newValue }
}
```

This is a better way to hide the tab bar to my mind, because the frame of the view controllers will be adjusted.

Comment: That's an awesome solution! Thanks! It made everything work just the way I needed. But I still can't quite understand, when is the set { ... } part of it triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you change constraint on keyboard show/Hide. Try to Google inputAccesoryView, many chats use it. It’s natural behaviour is to go with the keyboard. Try FaceBook Messenger for example and see there how swiping hides the keyboard and Textfield together, you can’t accomplish this kind od behaviour with regular view.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll definitely try googling and utilizing inputAccessoryView here.